# How wide is the beam of the death star's main weapon?

Tags: star-wars, movie, death-star

At the point of impact on the surface of a planet (or capital ship in the case of death star 2) how wide is the laser(?) beam of the death stars' main weapons?

From what I can see on-screen, there is little significant difference between the beam sizes of the death star and death star 2, but if there is evidence to the contrary that I'm unaware of, I'm more interested in death star 1, which is also the one with more on-screen evidence, and seemingly the most easily measurable information, especially [this](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-ee78362351064a12a030817f47720e36.webp) frame from Rogue One.

I'm primarily interested in on-screen evidence, from feature length films, other sources should only be used as corroboration, not as the primary sources of the answers. **EDIT In other words, if there is a source of information, separate from the films, that leads to an indication of this size, it should be used to confirm how on-screen images match that information, as opposed to being used to override or refute the on-screen images.  The film-based information is not meant to exclude other sources of information entirely but, instead, to take priority over any information that contradicts the on-screen information.**

Comment: If you're only interested in  film evidence, surely it would just be a matter of watching the films and saying "*that wide*"

Comment: @Valorum I'm not interested in "only" film based information, as that information seemingly contradicts itself from one image or sequence to the next, due to limitations of special effects and continuity discrepancies.  Instead, I'm interested in "only" information that does not directly contradict the on screen images, within the bounds of the already somewhat discrepant images.  Question edited to, hopefully, clarify this

Comment: Having no figures in Databank or Wookiepedia, and having no direct quote from the films/scripts, one can only guess.

Comment: @TimSparrow - Neither of those sources are exhaustive

Comment: @TimSparrow And that is also not an exhaustive list of potential resources